# How to create a upgrade system for a game (Mostly using enum)

Tags: java, enums, system, upgrade

Hello everyone and have a nice day. I'm trying to create a system similar to Asssassin's Creed Syndicate Upgrade system as you can see in the following picture which i took from google.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/30prp.jpg

Basically, you can take a upgrade, starting from top to bottom and everytime you buy a new upgrade the previous either is replaced or remains. Example 3 Upgrade can be the following:

1. Scavenger I
2. Scavenger II
3. Looter

When you buy Scavenger II it will replace the Scavenger I (which will give more chance to loot specific items), but then when you buy the 3rd upgrade which is Looter it won't replace the Scavenger. So basically you will have Scavenger II + Looter both active.

My code is the following:

```
public static enum Unlock
{
    /** Notoriety */
    SLEIGHT (1, 30, "Your sleight hands does not let any evidence behind, you get 30% less karma for your kills"),
    NOTORIETY (2, true , "Gaurds will make blind eyes and won't hunt you down upon a pk action."),

    /** Market */
    BARGAIN (3, 7, "You are a good bargain, anything you buy from any NPC will now cost 7% less."),
    TRADER (3, 14, "You achieved to be a good trader, market owners make you 14% discount from any NPC."),
    MARKETING (3, 25, "You own the market, anything you buy from any NPC will now cost 25% less."),

    /** Item */
    LOOTER(4, 7, "You became experienced in looting, you have now 7% chance to loot double adena"),
    TREASURE_HUNTER(4, 14, "You became advanced adventurer, you have now 14% chance to loot double double"),
    ADVENTURER(4, 21, "You became extremely good in looting items, you have now 21% chance to loot double double"),

    /** Couple */
    LOVER (5, true, "There is a huge bond between you and your partner, upon death your fiance get max healed."),
    FAITHFUL (5, true, "Your bond survived over the years. Upon death your fiance will receive beyond imagination support for few seconds."),

    /** Death */
    TRICKSTER (7, 0, "You can trick the death, you no longer receive death penalty upon deaths."),
    TRICKSTER_II (7, 10, "You can trick the death, your items has 10% less chance to drop upon death."),
    TRICKSTER_III (7, 25, "You can trick the death, your items has 25% less chance to drop upon death."),
    TRICKSTER_IV (7, 50, "You can trick the death, your items has 50% less chance to drop upon death.");

    private final int _groupId;
    private final Object _value;
    private final String _desc;

    private Unlock(final int groupId, final Object value, final String desc)
    {
        _groupId = groupId;
        _value = value;
        _desc = desc;
    }

    public int getId()
    {
        return _groupId;
    }

    public final Object getValue()
    {
        return _value;
    }

    public final String getDescription()
    {
        return _desc;
    }
}
```

So I made an enum which I have to say I'm a big fan of enums cause it makes the code readable. What I want is an idea on how to make my code like datagram. 
Right now i call my code in every method that i want to apply the upgrade like this:

```
itemDropPercent = itemDropPercent - (int) player.getUnlockables().getUnlockable(UnlockAction.DEATH, 0);
```

The 0 is the default value if the player does not have the specific upgrade. 
The UnlockAction is another enum I made:

```
public static enum UnlockAction
{
    MARKET (Unlock.MARKETING, Unlock.TRADER, Unlock.BARGAIN),
    COUPLE (Unlock.FAITHFUL, Unlock.LOVER),
    DEATH(Unlock.TRICKSTER_IV, Unlock.TRICKSTER_III, Unlock.TRICKSTER_II, Unlock.TRICKSTER),
    ITEM(Unlock.LOOTER);

    final Unlock[] _values;

    private UnlockAction(final Unlock ...values)
    {
        _values = values;
    }
}
```

that works like a list and goes one by one to the unlocks. 
So how else I could make this in order to make a dynamic system with upgrades?

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Could you provide signature and short implementation of  `getUnlockable` and `getUnlockables` methods?

Comment: Hello sir and thank you very much for your respond. I uploaded my full code on pastebin.com  https://pastebin.com/iHAMrkd5

Comment: Ok, I'll see it on pastebin. But could you please insert it to the question? It will help another people who will search by questions.

Comment: Anyone can help?